# what's difference between two syntax in using Consumer object?

Tags: java, lambda

i read following code from this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.function/Consumer/index.htm) and run it in eclipse and every thing was fine.

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.function.Consumer; 
/* w w w .j a va2s . c o m*/ 

public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    List<Student> students = Arrays.asList( new Student("John", 3), new Student("Mark", 4) );

    acceptAllEmployee(students, e -> System.out.println(e.name)); 
    acceptAllEmployee(students, e -> { e.gpa *= 1.5; }); 
    acceptAllEmployee(students, e -> System.out.println(e.name + ": " + e.gpa)); 
}

public static void acceptAllEmployee(List<Student> student, Consumer<Student> printer) { 
    for (Student e : student) { printer.accept(e); } } 
} 

class Student { public String name; public double gpa; Student(String name, double g) { 
    this.name = name; this.gpa = g; } 
}
```

then i decide to add this line of code just below the list declaration:

```
Consumer c = (e) -> {System.out.println(e.name);};
```

and surprisingly it cause an error!!

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code, since there was no problem in the original code in writing `e.name` in lambda expression, while still type of e was unknown, but in my code it's a problem!

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
name cannot be resolved or is not a field
  at com.test.Main.main(ExamineCharsets.java:9)
```

Thanks.

Comment: you are so angry feeling unwelcome! I used debugger and can't figure out what's the problem, sorry i'm not smart enough!

Comment: "name cannot be resolved" refers to `e.name` - [Georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460169/3284624) is correct in that you need to specify the type of the `Consumer` because if you don't specify that it consumes `Student` it will consume `Object` which has no `name`

Comment: it's true, but what about the lambda expression in the original code? there type of consumer doesn't specify and it still compile correctly!

Comment: @feelfree it is specified in your method signature: `public static void acceptAllEmployee(List<Student> student, Consumer<Student> printer)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the type of the consumer parameter in order to use its fields:

```
Consumer<Student> c = (e) -> {System.out.println(e.name);};
```